# React Component with passed down props not displaying with the rest of the page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, npm, vite

```
import React from 'react';
const WorkItem = ({ year, title, duration, details }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ol className="flex flex-col md:flex-row relative border-l border-stone-200">

        <li className="mb-10 ml-4">

          <div className="absolute w-3 h-3 bg-stone-200 rounded-full mt-1.5 -left-1.5 border-white" />
          <p className="flex flex-wrap gap-4 flex-row items-center justify-start text-x5 md:text-sm">
            <span className="inline-block px-2 py-1 font-semibold text-white bg-[#001b5e] rounded-md">
              {year}
            </span>

            <span className="text-lg font-semibold text-[#001b5e]">
              {title}
            </span>

            <span className="my-1 text-sm font-normal leading-none text-stone-400">
              {duration}
            </span>
          </p>

          <p className="my-2 text-base font-normal">{details}</p>
        </li>

      </ol>

    </div>
  );
};
```

I have declared the Prototype library because of Eslint errors am getting.
Firstly, I created an array of data in a different component(work.jsx) and maped over it and displayed it with the "WorkItem" component. each time I hover over it, it gives me the details of the corresponding data to show that the mapping was done correctly, but when I pass them as props to the 'workItem' component, I get a red line  underline error because of the way I destructured the props but they disappeared when I used Prop-type package but that part of the page is still blank.
I tried different stuffs like passing in 'props' as parameter and using it this way <Work {...props}.
I also tried this also; const {props, props, props} = props . I had to use brackets instead of curly braces. e.g const [props, props] = props but it still didn't work. I feel like my implementation is right but I don't know why this is happening. I have had to turn off my anti-virus and change browsers but it's the same result. SOS please!
bottom line, that part of the page, i.e the component is not displaying on my page like the rest of the components. I need help on how to fix that ASAP

Comment: can you add the parent component?

Comment: This is the parent component

import { data } from "./workData";
import WorkItem from "./WorkItem";

const Work = () => {
  return (
    <div id="work" className="max-w-[1040px] m-auto md:pl-20 p-4 py-16">
      <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold text-center text-[#001b5e]">Work</h1>
      {data.map((item, idx) => {
        <WorkItem
          key={idx}
          year={item.year}
          title={item.title}
          duration={item.duration}
          details={item.details}
        />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Work;